# chkdsk on a mirrored drive

Tags: windows-7, software-raid

I am running Windows 7 and have two 1TB hard drives mirrored using disk management.  (The mirrored drives are not the system disk.)

I am getting NTFS Error events that say "The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolume2."  Disk management reports both drives online and healthy.

Is running chkdsk on one drive of a mirror possible?  The logical drive E: reports OK with chkdsk.  Perhaps I need to break the mirror and rebuild it after chkdsk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could break the raid to be safe. CHKDSK checks the NTFS file system for corruption, which is exatly what you want. There shouldn't be any issues running chkdsk on a software raid. If this is in fact a hardware raid, run the check via the boot utility or the installed raid utility.

Comment: It is a windows software raid. What is the command to check just one drive?

Answer (score 1):

Guess something got stuck. Just break and rebuild. (Also, a chkdsk on both drives won't hurt. You can check the SMART values too.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check an individual drive directly -- you have to break it first, as you guessed, but there is another way as I will show further down.

First run chkdsk on the mirrored drive, and that should really fix the problem.  I would be surprised if one drive had file-system structural-problems needing chkdsk, and the other one didn't, as the disk volumes should be (literally) mirror copies of each other, but you can test that possibility out as follows next.

You can use [Paragon Backup & Recovery](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/br-free/), which has a USB-stick mini operating system that you can create which will allow you to load up the disks without affecting them.  So, for each disk individually, you can backup the disk, restore that backup to an empty drive, and then bring up that restored copy in Windows and chkdsk it from there.  I know Windows 10 recognizes either drive, but they are, in fact, different, and I have found that (with my older version of Paragon) Paragon recognizes one of the pair just fine, but the other appears to be completely empty (when it's not).  If Paragon sees both mirrored disks at the same time, they are both properly recognized.  But there must be some actual difference between the two drives, probably one is the working image, and the other is the backup image -- that's my guess.

If you have two extra empty drives, you can backup the pair (the whole mirror) and then bring the backed-up pair up in Windows, break the backed-up mirrored pair, and chkdsk individually (to prove to yourself whether one is messed-up, but the other is fine).  If the Disk Management Mirroring is working properly, the disks should either both be good, or both need a chkdsk.  If they are out of synchronization, please let us know, because that would be a serious reliability problem (and Thanks, if you do).

Finally, if getting a power outage before both mirrored volumes are synchronized, to me, that strongly argues for both running chkdsk automatically on a regular schedule, and also perhaps leaning towards using SSD's, as I have noticed that they take less time to update, generally speaking.  I am arguing that If the disks update faster, there is more of a chance that they will finish writing what they have to write before power is lost.  Still should regularly run chkdsk, though, IMO.  Hope this helps.